# Unaligned columns

Tags: tables, beamer

I am trying to put different verbs conjugated in a table but the first columns is not aligned with the first person etc.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}


\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\newcommand*\cancel[2][thin]{\tikz[baseline] \node [strike out,draw,anchor=text,inner sep=0pt,text=black,#1]{#2};}


\setbeamertemplate{items}[ball] 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 



\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{Cores}
\begin{tabular}{@{\quad}l@{\quad}l@{\quad}l@{\quad}l@{\quad}l}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{black!5}{\textbf{pron.} }}& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{black!5}{\textbf{ser} }} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{black!5}{\textbf{ter} }}& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{black!5}{\textbf{gostar} }}& \multicolumn{1}{l}{\cellcolor{black!5}{\textbf{chamar-se} }}\\
\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\arrayrulecolor{black!5}
\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}\arrayrulecolor{black}
% \midheading{Present} & \midheading{Present} & \midheading{Present} \\
eu & sou & tenho & gosto & chamo-me \\
tu & és & tens & gostas & chamas-te \\
ele & é & tem & gosta & chama-se \\
nós & somos & temos & gostamos & chamamo-nos \\
eles & são & têm & gostam & chamam-se \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile for me. There is no `\end{document}`

Answer (score 3):

The code of your table seems unnecessarily complex, instead of trying to debug it, I would simply suggest to use something like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={table}]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Cores}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \rowcolor{black!5}
        \textbf{pron.} & \textbf{ser} & \textbf{ter} & \textbf{gostar} & \textbf{chamar-se}\\
        \midrule
        eu & sou & tenho & gosto & chamo-me \\
        tu & és & tens & gostas & chamas-te \\
        ele & é & tem & gosta & chama-se \\
        nós & somos & temos & gostamos & chamamo-nos \\
        eles & são & têm & gostam & chamam-se \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Personal opinion:** I would not use coloured rows in your table. Simply place a `\toprule` above and remove the colour and you'll get a nice looking table.

**Off-topic:** you don't need `\usepackage{color}` nor `\usepackage{xcolor}` with beamer. To use the `colortbl` it is best to pass the `table` option to `xcolor`.

Comment: the preamble may also be a `\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
...`

Comment: @Zarko Good catch, thank you! I edited my answer.